# Can a hit and run victim sue the car owner for not having insurance?

Tags: small-claims-court, accident-insurance, idaho

An adult driver hit-and-ran someone who found the car later at the driver's mom's house. Her son had been driving but she owned the car. She talked to the police and gave them the insurance card, which had expired 9 months prior. If one sued the son in small claims court for the damages, could one sue her also? She has more assets so a victim could be fully paid sooner than just from her son.

UPDATE 1:
Jurisdiction is Bonneville County, Idaho; inside Idaho Falls city limits.

Re: previous question, I didn't word it well, and some users edited it to remove information which caused answers that weren't applicable anymore. I decided to narrow the focus and try asking again.

UPDATE 2:
Damages are about $5k. A cop told me later that she's alo responsible for costs because she didn't have insurance, that's where I got the idea about sueing her also. I don't know if he's wrong.

Idaho is an at-fault state and requires proof of $25k/$15k bodily and property liability insurance before registering a car. He lives with her and drives her car; therefore he should be on her insurance. They also check VIN every two months with a nationwide database to ensure they still have insurance. Violations include suspended car registration, license suspension, and required SR-22 insurance (expensive). Second violation is up to six months jail and up to $1k fine.

The mom has court history of not having car insurance, but they've been dismissed. It's odd she didn't have card in car each time, so she either she really does forget to put in her car, or she buys a policy the same day as citation to prove to court she was insured and get charges dismissed.

I think she does have insurance, but gave officer cancelled card so she only pays $75 ticket, her rates don't go up, and her son can make payments over several years. I hope by suing her with son, that I can force her to bring forth the insurance or risk a lien on her house, force sale of valuable items, etc.

That's why I'm hoping to include her in lawsuit.

Comment: This site is not for direct legal advice; talk to a lawyer or the small claims court in your area.

Comment: I think this can probably be answered without giving legal advice, but we'd need to know what jurisdiction it refers to.

Comment: edited to make question hypothetical

Comment: Jurisdiction matters - in my home jurisdiction, the insurance responsibility is up to the driver, not the vehicle owner and its perfectly possible to own a vehicle, never drive it, and never have insurance for it. But the moment someone else jumps into it and drives it without ensuring they have insurance, they've committed a criminal act (Driving without Insurance).  Again, my jurisdiction.

Comment: Previous question about the same case. It's in Idaho. https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/64130/how-to-get-current-insurance-information-from-car-owner-of-sons-hit-and-run-cha

Comment: In most jurisdictions, Hit and Run usually flips the fault of the crash to the person who fled the scene, even if the facts of the case were the driver who remained would have been at fault.

Comment: Was it simply the card that had expired or the woman's actual insurance? The cards are only good for a ridiculously short time that most people probably only have, at best, one that is at least one term out-of-date (if not several) in their car/wallet/whatever.

Comment: No, when insurance was called next day company said it expired 9 months before, and sent a letterhead officially confirming it. Wouldn't that be proof of a crime?

Comment: Thank you @GeorgeWhite, if all I have to do is change "Can I do..." to "Can a person do..." then I'll try to write questions in that way in law.SE. Thank you for showing me that.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch comments like that discourage users from using SE. I'm asking so I'm informed before I talk to a lawyer. I'll take this up on meta, but I'm really frustrated with some users like you on law.SE. Every other SE users ask questions about their specific situation because we seek specific Professional Advise. Excel: "What's best solution to..." DIY: "Can this be repaired?" Drupal: "How can I..." These questions aren't open ended or philosophical. If users only need a Fact they can google it and there's no point for law.SE. Thankfully most everyone else is fantastic about it.

Comment: @KirkHings - this site requires a different style of question becasue it is not illegal to give advice on DIY, interpersonal skills, chess, etc. but can be illegal regarding how to apply the law to a specific person's situation.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite, I see what you mean. Wouldn't posting in header of every page something like "This is opinion not legal advice, seek a lawyer ...."? Like newspaper opinion pages, you can't get sued because supreme court says everyone has right to opinion.

Comment: @KirkHings What you have failed to read is the disclaimer sidebar, and what you fail to understand that it is illegal to give legal advice if not an attorney and not in an attorney-client relationship, and it's stupid to ignore that and take legal advice from randos on the web. It's really for your own best interest, so you need to understand the difference in asking advice about Excel and advice that can cost you a lot of money and legal exposure.

Comment: Sidebar: "Law Stack Exchange is for educational purposes only and is not a substitute for individualized advice from a qualified legal practitioner. Communications on Law Stack Exchange are not privileged communications and do not create an attorney-client relationship." Why doesn't that indemnify users then?

Comment: https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221/policy-for-questions-that-clearly-ask-for-specific-legal-advice/222

Comment: @KirkHings - If you look at enough questions here you will soon see that this policy of closing questions with "I" in the title is enforced very unevenly. An answer that says "get a lawyer" will usually be found when the OP seems to be a very serious pickle.

Comment: That page conflicts the sidebar then. Please help me understand why. You could have just pointed me to the page and told me to edit the question to make it hypothetical. Instead you told me to beat feet out of here and go pay a lawyer instead of getting a smidgeon of knowledge before I do that. Then telling me I've failed to understand and am stupid when what you're citing is in conflict. This is the kind of experience that turns users off from SE.

Comment: Here's a relevant argument against what you're saying: https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279/questions-that-appear-to-seek-legal-advice

Answer (score 12):

You can't sue her for not having insurance. You sue for the damage you suffered.

You can name her as a defendant alongside her son on the theory that she contributed to the accident by letting her son use the car, and then let the judge sort out who gets landed with the liability. Depending on the rules in your jurisdiction you might have to pay her travel expenses and/or lost wages if the judge decides she wasn't to blame (and the same for her son, but that sounds like a slam-dunk).

However you might be better off going for [victim restitution](https://www.cdaid.org/1271/departments/legal/prosecuting-attorneys-office/restitutioncrime-victim-compensation). That way the order gets made as part of the criminal case against the son. Less hassle for you, and the state authorities are responsible for actually getting the money out of them.

**Edit:** It turns out that Idaho has the [Family Car Doctrine](https://legislature.idaho.gov/statutesrules/idstat/title49/t49ch24/sect49-2417/) in its law, so the mother is legally liable for her son's accident (thanks to ohwilleke for the pointer).

Comment: Mom has many more assets than her 25 year old son. Restitution from son will take years. Restitution including Mom can be resolved much faster (hopefully).

Comment: But the fact that she has no insurance is causing me damages. So was she legally required to have insurance? Or was she legally required to make sure that nobody without insurance drives the car?

Comment: @gnasher729 Turns out you can sue the mother. https://legislature.idaho.gov/statutesrules/idstat/title49/t49ch24/sect49-2417/ I've also added this to the answer.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yes, it's an at-fault state and requires proof of $25k/$15k bodily and property liability insurance before registering a car. County DMV also checks VIN every two months, using a nationwide database to ensure they still have insurance. Driver's are notified if they don't have any, and if they don't provide proof of insurance within 30 days, car registration is suspended. Other violations include license suspension, and required SR-22 insurance (expensive). Second violation is up to six months jail and up to $1k fine.

Answer (score 4):

Only rarely can the victim sue for not having insurance in most, but one can can sue mom for damages under the [Family Car Doctrine](https://www.shafnerlaw.com/blog/colorados-family-car-doctrine-explained/#:%7E:text=Colorado%20is%20one%20of%2020,minor%20children%20or%20legal%20dependents.&text=The%20liable%20parent%20must%20be,have%20control%20over%20the%20vehicle.) in Colorado and nineteen other U.S. states, which holds householders vicariously liable for all torts caused using cars that are part of their household. Some other jurisdictions impose vicarious liability on a car owner and it is usually a crime to fail to carry sufficient insurance (which doesn't put money in the victim's pocket).

Answer (score 0):

[new-south-wales](/questions/tagged/new-south-wales)

### Insurance for New South Wales

**Compulsory Third Party (CTP)**

Compulsory injury insurance that is required before a motor vehicle can be registered. Although called “third-party” it does provide more limited coverage for an at-fault driver who is injured.

If someone is driving an uninsured vehicle, the person is committing an offence (as is the owner for allowing the driver to drive) but the insurance cover is still available with the state as the insurer of last resort. They can recover from the owner or driver.

**Third party property**

This covers damage done by the vehicle to other people’s property.

It is not mandatory.

**Comprehensive**

This covers damage done by the vehicle to other people’s property as well as the vehicle itself.

It is not mandatory.

### [Liability](https://www.lawaccess.nsw.gov.au/Pages/representing/lawassist_car_accident/who_is_responsible/owners_and_drivers.aspx)

The at-fault driver is responsible for property damage they cause.

The owner of the at-fault vehicle is *also* liable if the driver is an agent of the owner.

A person may be an agent of the owner, if the owner:

- asks the driver to drive their car for the owner's purpose
- has some control over how the driver uses their car.

Comment: Curious why this was downvoted? It seems to describe the insurance and law issues in the case. See updated question.

Comment: @KirkHings: I didn't downvote, but note the tag at the top: It describes how the insurance and law issues would be *if* you lived in New South Wales.

Comment: Oh. I didn't see that. Thank you for pointing that out.